# While loop syntax error will not compile even when trying to break out

Tags: c, while-loop, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error and cannot find where i am not completing the loop. my program is to query for what to convert to then after it converts asks the user if they want to do it again and if yes, present option menu again.

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){ 
    char answer;
    int selection;
    int again = 0;
    printf("Select Conversion:\n");
    printf("(1.)Hex to Binary\n(2.)Binary to Hex\n");
    scanf("%d", &selection);
    while (again != 1) 
    {
        if (selection ==1)
        {
            char bin2[1000], hexa2[1000];
            long int a = 0;
            printf("Enter a hex or binary value: "); 
            scanf("%s", &hexa2);
            printf("\nBinary value: ");
            while (hexa2[a])
            {
                switch (hexa2[a])
                {
                case '0':
                    printf("0000"); 
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("0001"); 
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("0010"); 
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("0011"); 
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("0100"); 
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("0101"); 
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("0110"); 
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("0111"); 
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("1000"); 
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("1001"); 
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    printf("1010"); 
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    printf("1011"); 
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    printf("1100"); 
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    printf("1101"); 
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    printf("1110"); 
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    printf("1111"); 
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    printf("1010"); 
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    printf("1011"); 
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    printf("1100"); 
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    printf("1101"); 
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    printf("1110"); 
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    printf("1111"); 
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %c ", hexa2[a]);
                    return 0;
                }
                a++;
            break;
            }
        }   
            
        if (selection == 2)
        {
            long int bin, hex = 0, i = 1, left;
            printf("Enter Binary Number: \n");
            scanf("%ld", &bin);
            while (bin != 0)
            {
                left = bin % 10;
                hex = hex + left * i;
                i = i * 2;
                bin = bin / 10;
            }
            printf("Hexadecimal value: %lX", hex);
        }
        printf("\nContinue(Y/N)?\n");
        scanf("%s", &answer);
        if (answer=='Y'||answer=='y')
            {
                again = again +2;
            }
            else
            {
                again=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Exit");
    return 0;
    
}
```

I keep getting a syntax error and cannot find where i am not completing the loop. my program is to query for what to convert to then after it converts asks the user if they want to do it again and if yes, present option menu again.

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: looks like you have an extra `}` at line number  124

Comment: Yep - there is an extra `}` immediately before the last `printf` line. The strange indentation  you use for the preceding `if ... else` block is muddying the waters.

Comment: Error:(126): warning undefined type or identifier (assuming int):_printf,126): error syntax error.(126): warning absurd type - ignored.(127): error syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    char answer;
    int selection;
    do
    {
        printf("Select Conversion:\n");
        printf("(1.)Hex to Binary\n(2.)Binary to Hex\n");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        if (selection == 1)
        {
            char bin2[1000], hexa2[1000];
            long int a = 0;
            printf("Enter a hex value: ");
            scanf("%s", hexa2);
            printf("\nBinary value: ");
            while (hexa2[a])
            {
                switch (hexa2[a])
                {
                case '0':
                    printf("0000");
                    break;
                case '1':
                    printf("0001");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    printf("0010");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    printf("0011");
                    break;
                case '4':
                    printf("0100");
                    break;
                case '5':
                    printf("0101");
                    break;
                case '6':
                    printf("0110");
                    break;
                case '7':
                    printf("0111");
                    break;
                case '8':
                    printf("1000");
                    break;
                case '9':
                    printf("1001");
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    printf("1010");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    printf("1011");
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    printf("1100");
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    printf("1101");
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    printf("1110");
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    printf("1111");
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    printf("1010");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    printf("1011");
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    printf("1100");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    printf("1101");
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    printf("1110");
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    printf("1111");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("\n Invalid hexa digit %c ", hexa2[a]);
                    return 0;
                }
                a++;
            }
        }

        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            long int bin, hex = 0, i = 1, left;
            printf("Enter Binary Number: \n");
            scanf("%ld", &bin);
            while (bin != 0)
            {
                left = bin % 10;
                hex = hex + left * i;
                i = i * 2;
                bin = bin / 10;
            }
            printf("Hexadecimal value: %lX", hex);
        }
        printf("\nContinue(Y/N)?\n");
        scanf("%s", &answer);
    } while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
    printf("Exit");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does! it all converts correctly now but still don't get the prompt for the user on either one should i move that out?

Comment: convert 12 to decimal your code will give 0001

Comment: im converting only hex to binary and binary to hex

Comment: I  changed the prompt so it makes more sense. it supposed to convert either hex to binary or binary to

Comment: convert 12 to binary your code will give 0001

Comment: This last code works except i can't get it to print past the second hex value: right now if i enter 7a for option 1 it gives me 0111 and nothing for a but does prompt correctly. im looking at it. I appreciate all your help

Comment: It was my compiler. tried a few others and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Now look in the code and try to observe it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has more `}` than `{`. Remove the extra `}` here:

```
        if (answer=='Y'||answer=='y')
            {
                again = again +2;
            }
            else
            {
                again=1;
            }
        }
```

Also, change `scanf("%s", &hexa2);` to `scanf("%s", hexa2);`. For `%s`, a `char *` should be passed. `hexa2` is an array of 1000 `char` (`char [1000]`), so `&hexa2` is a pointer to an array of 1000 `char` (`char (*)[1000]`). When you use `hexa2` as an argument, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first argument, so that will be a `char *`.

Comment: Ok when i remove that bracket it now runs but when i select the first option now it does not convert hex to binary past the first number. and selection 2 converts correctly but neither prompt to start again it just sits. any ideas?

Comment: your variable `answer` is just a `char` but you are reading as string in here `scanf("%s", &answer);`

Comment: Yes because for some reason when ihave it at "%c" it automatically selects an option but when i put "%s" it allows me to input a y or n and continues correctly

Comment: use `scanf(" %c", &answer);` (a space before %) instead of `scanf("%s", &answer);`